# Looking for nomenclature! What is it called to remove all parts of a cycle that have no area?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Given this directed graph:
[image]
And the cycle A->B->C->D->E->F->E->D->G->B->A (so simply going around the graph clockwise):

**What is it the operation called to eliminate all parts of this cycle that have no area, so that the result would be B->C->D->G->B?**

Another problem description maybe would be: To find the minimal cycle with the same area.

I read on wikipedia that A->B->A for example would be a digon (cycle of length 2), so am I "eliminating digons" from the cycle, or how would I describe this, so that other people familiar with graph theory understand what I'm trying to do here?

I do this exact thing in a programm of mine (to prevent 0-area polygons to be formed), and am really struggling with appropriate naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard term for this: you should introduce one of your own and **clearly define** it when it's introduced. (This happens pretty frequently, there are a lot of simple constructions out there which don't have specific names.) "Removing digons" makes sense, and another one which appeals to me is "cancel edges" (thinking of an edge $AB$ as the inverse of an edge $BA$ - this has the advantage of making sense even when we allow multiple arrows with the same source and target and we care about multiplicity).